# conda build doesn't include the lib files in the .bz2.

Tags: conda, conda-build

I am trying to build my own package with conda build 
However once its produced the .bz2 file and I extract

I can see the following:

```
|-- about.json
|-- files
|-- index.json
|-- paths.json
`-- recipe
    |-- bld.bat
    |-- build.sh
    |-- meta.yaml
    `-- meta.yaml.template
```

Am I missing the lib folder if am not mistaking. 
It does the whole dowload package and extract and built

Comment: What is the contents of your `meta.yaml` and `build.sh` files?

Comment: I took the meta.yaml and build.sh from https://github.com/conda/conda-recipes/tree/master/boost made couple of changes to set some additional flags with -fPIC. it builds successfully

Comment: When you unzip the `.tar.bz2` file, it should create multiple directories (`include`, `lib`, `info`).  Your file listing shown above is just the contents of the `info` directory.  Look one level above that for the `lib` directory.  Don't look in the `info` directory.

Comment: when i unzip the .tar.bz2 file it only contains this info folder nothing else

Comment: did you solve this ?